# How to load file via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to learn how Ajax works so I wrote couple of scripts but when I have been clicking the button, the page.html is not being loaded!
I'm using jQuery v1.11.1 
index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

<title>Demo</title>
</head>

  <body> 
   <input id="button" type="button"  value="Load" />
   <div id="content"></div>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

ajax.js

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'page.html',
  succuss: function(data){
   $('#content').html(data);
  }
 });
});
```

page.html

```html
<strong>Loaded Ok!</strong>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change this:

Client side :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.html',
    success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    } 
});
```

for this (success not succuss :P):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.html',
    method: 'get',
    success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    } 
});
```

Also check your JavaScript console if you get an error like: "$ is not defined". Then change all "$" in your ajax.js to "jQuery" or:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.html',
        method: 'get',
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        } 
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks yes that was typo :) I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

add method of ajax request to your code as following :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'page.html',
        type:'post',
        succuss: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
```